# Find the coefficientof $x^n$ in the expansion of $\frac{2-3{x}}{2x^2-3x+1}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, multinomial-coefficients

The coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of $$\frac{2-3{x}}{2x^2-3x+1} $$

How to proceed on this question ?

Answer (score 2):

Wite $$\frac{2-3x}{(1-x)(1-2x)}=\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{1}{1-2x}$$
and use binomial coefficients.